# What is the reason for old questions to pop up?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

It is not the first time that I notice a situation, when an old, already answered question pops up. Previously I thought that such things happen, since somebody has recently seen it and, say, up- or down-voted it, or left a comment (which is invisible, at least, not immediately visible).

However, today I see my own [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46048/a-box-for-the-integral-or-partial-derivative-d) asked in April again on the list. This was a very special question. At the time it gained no votes and had no answers. Finally I answered it myself. My answer also gained no votes. The subject seems to be finalized. However, it is up today with the same situation: still no votes and no new answers, or comments.

So I wonder, why did it pop up? What is the mechanism?

Comment: [Community](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) automatically modifies questions from unanswered stack so they could get attention/answers/upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it is up today with the same situation: still no votes and no new answers, or comments.

And that's why it got pushed to the front page: because it got no attention the first two times. As Kuba noted, this is [an automated process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Answer (score 0):

> However, it is up today with the same situation: still no votes and no new answers, or comments.

And that's why it got pushed to the front page: because it got no attention the first two times. As Kuba noted, this is [an automated process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

See also: [Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-%E2%99%A6-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511)